# Get 2 elements per loop from N lengh array

Tags: php, arrays

I have seen similar questions but I feel mine is different, I have a 2 column page which needs 2 users per row, issue is when I have an array that has an odd length, the last element does not come out here is my logic

```
<?php for($i = 0; $i < count($team); $i++){
      echo "Looping ".$i;  
      ?>
      <div class="row">
             <?php for($z = $i; $z < 2; $z++){
              echo "inner Looping ".$z?>
            <div class="col s12 m6 grid">
              <figure class="effect-honey">
                <img src="<?php echo  $team[$z]['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo  $team[$z]['fname']. ' '.$team[$z]['lname']; ?>"/>
                <figcaption>
                  <h2><?php echo  $team[$z]['fname']; ?><span><?php echo  $team[$z]['lname']; ?></span> <i><?php echo  $team[$z]['position']; ?></i></h2>
                </figcaption>     
              </figure>
            </div>
          <?php $i = $z;} ?>
          </div>
      <?php } ?>
      </div>
```

[A sample of the output of an array with 3 items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVSR8.png)

Comment: Try with an array of 10 items, you'll get why it doesn't works, your logic is wrong with the 2nd loop

Comment: @AymDev yes it is, am hoping i could get help on how to make the second loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `array_chunk()` on `$team` with `2` as the chunk size parameter. Then you can use an outer `foreach()` to iterate the generated pairs and an inner `foreach()` to display the subarrays.

Assuming you don't need to write empty html elements for the missing 2nd element in odd-count scenarios, here is an implementation (there are a few ways to do this).

Code ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/3Y3GN))

```
$team = [
    ['image' => 'A.jpg', 'fname' => 'B', 'lname' => 'C', 'position' => 'D'],
    ['image' => 'E.jpg', 'fname' => 'F', 'lname' => 'G', 'position' => 'H'],
    ['image' => 'I.jpg', 'fname' => 'J', 'lname' => 'K', 'position' => 'L']
];
$pairs = array_chunk($team, 2);
foreach ($pairs as $pair) {
    echo "<div class=\"row\">";
        foreach ($pair as $player) {
            echo "<div class=\"col s12 m6 grid\">";
                echo "<figure class=\"effect-honey\">";
                    echo "<img src=\"{$player['image']}\" alt=\"{$player['fname']} {$player['lname']}\"/>";
                    echo "<figcaption>";
                        echo "<h2>{$player['fname']}<span>{$player['lname']}</span> <i>{$player['position']}</i></h2>";
                    echo "</figcaption>";
                echo "</figure>";
            echo "</div>";
        }
    echo "</div>";
}
```

Output:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m6 grid">
        <figure class="effect-honey">
            <img src="A.jpg" alt="B C"/>
            <figcaption>
                <h2>B<span>C</span> <i>D</i></h2>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="col s12 m6 grid">
        <figure class="effect-honey">
            <img src="E.jpg" alt="F G"/>
            <figcaption>
                <h2>F<span>G</span> <i>H</i></h2>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m6 grid">
        <figure class="effect-honey">
            <img src="I.jpg" alt="J K"/>
            <figcaption>
                <h2>J<span>K</span> <i>L</i></h2>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you require an empty (space-holding) portion of html when the "right-side" player is missing, please clarify your question / desired result.